# Script to make mulitple directories and copy a file to them all

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

Scripting is unfortunately a weak point of mine so I come to the scripting gods for help which should be relatively basic for you all here I'm sure.

The situation is that we need make multiple folders and then copy an .ini file to the new directory location on a terminal server.

The location = c:\users\%users%\appdata\roaming\sap\common

The file =  c:\itworking\saplogin.ini

It's the \sap\common part of the directory above that's missing from everyone's DIR path that needs to be made.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you simply need to include `mkdir c:\users\%users%\appdata\roaming\sap\`and `mkdir c:\users\%users%\appdata\roaming\sap\common` in your script.

This will be called only once, near the top of the script.

It is not clear, though, what you mean by "multiple folders".  Is this on multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=U:\users"
SET "approam=appdata\roaming"
SET "commonfile=u:\firebell.xtx"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*" '
  ) DO (
 ECHO %%a
 IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%a\%approam%" (
  XCOPY "%commonfile%" "%destdir%\%%a\%approam%\sap\common\" >nul
 )
)

DIR/s u:\firebell*


GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `destdir` and `commonfile` to suit your circumstances. The final `dir` simply lists the resultant files of interest. It would need to be adjusted to suit (if required.)

Answer (score 0):

@Magoo: Thanks Magoo; I'll give that a shot and let you know how it goes!

@Thom: I think you got it really; create a new folder and sub-folder for all user profiles (multiple DIRs) then copy a single .ini file to the newly created folder for all users.

Cheers!

Jeff